# JavaScript/Angular - Issue while trying to style Google Maps using a local JSON file

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular, google-maps-api-3

I am facing a very weird issue while trying to style Google Maps.

Usually to style a Google Maps you do the following:

```
var styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(this.jsonData,{name: "Styled Map"});
```

While `this.jsonData` is a long JSON file. I am importing a local JSON file and try to inject it into `new google.maps.StyledMapType` object; however, nothing changes ! On the other hand, when I assign the content of the same local JSON file to a variable, it works and changes the style of the map. However, I wouldn't like to keep the that long JSON array on the same page of my controller.

I am using the below to import the local JSON file:

```
mapStyleFile(){
     this.http.get("assets/json/mapStyle.json")
     .map((res) => res)
     .subscribe(data =>{
      this.jsonData = data["_body"];
    });
  }
```

Template JSON:

```
        [
            {
                "featureType": "all",
                "elementType": "all",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "hue": "#e7ecf0"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "administrative",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#636c81"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "administrative.neighborhood",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#636c81"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "administrative.land_parcel",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#ff0000"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "landscape",
                "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#f1f4f6"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "landscape",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#496271"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "poi",
                "elementType": "all",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "visibility": "off"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "all",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "saturation": -70
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#ffffff"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "geometry.stroke",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#c6d3dc"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "road",
                "elementType": "labels.text.fill",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#898e9b"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "transit",
                "elementType": "all",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "visibility": "off"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "all",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "visibility": "simplified"
                    },
                    {
                        "saturation": -60
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "featureType": "water",
                "elementType": "geometry.fill",
                "stylers": [
                    {
                        "color": "#d3eaf8"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You code will not detect the change of this.jsonData. You have to update your style after you load JSON.

```
mapStyleFile(){
     this.http.get("assets/json/mapStyle.json")
     .map((res) => res)
     .subscribe(data => {
      this.jsonData = data["_body"];
      let styledMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(this.jsonData,{name: "Styled Map"});
    });
}
```

Comment: Okay, is 'styledMapType' updated? Or you want something else? If you want the style updated after you load file, please post you template code. I can see how to update your view.

Comment: I've just updated my post, so now it contains the JSON file content. Now, if i take that content and I put it directly inside `new google.maps.StyledMapType()` it works as expected; however, when I call it using `this.http.get` it does not load!

Comment: I see. Check network tab in dev tools. The JSON file path might be wrong.

Comment: @wannadream I facing the same issue, and  it shows that the file is loading fine, but the style does not get applied to the map unless it's available locally, (i.e on the same file)